# Creating a thumbnail Navigation for a Flexslider

Tags: views, javascript

I want to create this:

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

Using Flexslider.

In Flexslider's Advanced Options I see there is an option to "Use as Navigation". I've tried setting another Flexslider slidehow (full of thumbnails) as the navigation but it doesn't seem to work right.

I just need to have a main slider and a slider under it full of thumbnails that acts as a navigation menu for the main slider. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean 'doesn't seem to work' what's the problem. what have you tried? Is there any output.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) module
- If you need to display images as a view, select "slider w/thumbnail controlnav pattern" option set in Flexslider display mode settings.
- If you displays images a multi-valued image field, select "slider w/thumbnail controlnav pattern" for the field in Manage display tab.

Please note that [controlNav pattern](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html) (you mentioned) is not the same as [thumbnail slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html).